# How to check the certain array is present in array of arrays, compare purely by its values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var a = [["attribute1", "param1", 1], ["attribute2", "param2", 2], ["attribute3", "param3", 3]];

var b = ["attribute1", "param1", 1];
```

How Could check the array "b" is present in array "a" in javascript, Compare just by values inside it?

I tried brute force method, I am Asking Is this can be done in efficient way using jQuery or underscore.js? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your question is unclear and you have not shown any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I tried brute force method, I am Asking Is this can be done in efficient way using jQuery or underscore.js?

Comment: So where's your code?

Comment: Then show what you tried, and explain how that result differed from the expected result

Comment: Those are different arrays containing the same values. Yes, you need to compare element by element.

Comment: Iterate through `a`, for each value in `a` iterate through `b` and if `b[j] !== a[i][j]` then exit the inner loop early.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks I Implemented using two for loops, I think that is not efficient, Is that a better way or already implemented this feature in jquery or underscore?

Comment: @MohamedHussain: That's as efficient as it gets. There might be shorter (more concise) ways of writing it, especially with the help of a library, but that's ultimately the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude and slower method could be

```
var isPresent =  a.filter(function(val){ return val.join("===") == b.join("==="); }).length > 0 ;
```

or

```
var isPresent =  a.filter(function(val){ return JSON.stringify(val) == JSON.stringify(b); }).length > 0 ;
```

A faster way could be

```
var isPresent =  a.filter(function(val){ 
  return val[0] == b[0] && val[1] == b[1] && val[2] == b[2] ; 
}).length > 0 ;
```

If number of items in a and b are more/less than 3 then

```
var isPresent = a.filter(function(val){ 
  return val.filter( function(item, index){
    return val[index] == b[index]
  } ).length > 0; 
}).length > 0;
```

Comment: Crude? Oh definitely. Not enough for a downvote, but I really wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: These all return `false` when it should be `true`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You want to use `.some(…)` instead of `.filter(…) > 0` (which should at least be `.filter(…).length > 0` to work)

Comment: @putvande yeah missed out in `.length`

Comment: Cool.. not going crazy :).

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_if_array_exists_in_array(a, b) {
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var arr = a[i];
    if(arr.length == b.length) {
      for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if(arr[j] !== b[j]) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the fiddle I made for you:

[JSFiddle - compare two arrays](https://jsfiddle.net/4hys6gLL/2/)

```
var a = [["attribute1", "param1", 1], ["attribute2", "param2", 2], ["attribute3", "param3", 3]];

var b = ["attribute1", "param1", 1];

var str = "",
    counter = 0;

//traverse through multidimensional array
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

  //cancel the nested loop if a result was found
  if (str === 'exist') {break;}

  //process length-matching arrays only
  if (a[i].length === b.length) {

    //loop through both array's values
    for (var x = 0; x < a[i].length; x++) {

      if (a[i][x] == b[x]) {

        //value match
        counter++;
        if (counter == b.length) {

          //equal arrays
          str = 'exist';
          break;
        }

      } else {

        //value mismatch
        counter = 0;
        str = 'not existing';
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {str = 'not existing';}
}
document.getElementById('fb').innerHTML = str;
```